# adding page break after table XWPF document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have image paths in my access database and I'm putting images in word document table. I want to add page break after each table. I wrote this codes to do this but it's not add page break after each table.

```
            int picturesCount=imgPaths.size();  
            int tableRows=(int)Math.round(picturesCount/2d);
            XWPFParagraph parag=document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run=parag.createRun();
            InputStream is2 = null;

            XWPFTable imgTable;
            XWPFTableCell cell;
            int TableRows=0;
            for(int c=0;c<imgPaths.size();c++)
            {
                if(!imgPaths.get(c).equals("-"))
                {
                    TableRows++;
                }
            }
            int rows=(int)Math.round(TableRows/2d);
            imgTable=document.createTable(rows,2);
            imgTable.removeBorders();
            int tableRow=0;
            int tableCell=0;
            int des=0;
            for(String pictureURL:imgPaths) {

                if(!"-".equals(pictureURL)) {
                    try {

                        cell=imgTable.getRow(tableRow).getCell(tableCell++);
                        if(tableCell==2) {
                            tableCell=0;
                            tableRow++;
                        }

                        is2 = new FileInputStream(pictureURL);
                        if(cell.getParagraphs().size()>0) parag=cell.getParagraphs().get(0);else parag=cell.addParagraph();
                        if(parag.getRuns().size()>0) run=parag.getRuns().get(0);else run=parag.createRun();
                        run.addPicture(is2, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "Images", Units.toEMU(250), Units.toEMU(250));
                        parag=cell.addParagraph();
                        run.setText(des_img.get(des));
                        des++;
                        run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0).getInlineArray(0).addNewCNvGraphicFramePr().addNewGraphicFrameLocks().setNoChangeAspect(true);

                    }  catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            parag.setPageBreak(true);
```

I wrote this code **parag.setPageBreak(true);** after each table end point.

Comment: You need creating a new paragraph after the table which then can have set `setPageBreak(true)`. So do `...} parag=document.createParagraph(); parag.setPageBreak(true);`